# I keep receiving "fish_pager cannot connect to universal variable server"

Tags: shell, console, linux-mint, fish, cinnamon

I keep receiving an error in fish:

> kmejka@kmejka ~> cd .c
> fish_pager: Could not connect to universal variable server, already tried manual restart (or no command supplied). You will not be able to share variable values between fish sessions. Is fish properly installed?
> .cache/  .cinnamon/  .config/

The error seems to appear on random without any  issues with the system, hard reboots, system failures, etc. Fish works normally, I didn't notice any errors, apart from this message when pressing <kbd>tab</kbd> to auto suggest paths.

How can I solve this issue?

I use Linux Mint 16, with Cinnamon. My console is started in Yakuake.

Fish version is 2.0.0

> kmejka@kmejka ~> fish --version
>
> fish, version 2.0.0

Comment: What version of fish do you have installed?

Comment: kmejka@kmejka ~> fish --version
fish, version 2.0.0

Comment: Is there anything illuminating in /tmp/fishd.log.username?

Comment: I have similar experience on Mac OS X. Not really a solution, but when I see this warning, I just restart iTerm2 and the warning goes away. Next time I check /tmp/fishd.log.username.

Comment: The error stopped occuring, it is too late for me to determine what was wrong then. I have since reinstalled my os, the problem stopped occuring.

Comment: You should validate the answer below. I had the same error and the method described in the answer worked fine for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem with fish, version 2.1.0.

The solution was to move the original .config/fish folder to another location and create a new .config/fish folder. Then I only moved config.fish and the functions/ folder from the old config folder to the newly created .config/fish folder. That worked for me!

Comment: Worked for me. Though there might be an explanation ? Did you figure out what made the fish_pager to break ?

Comment: I think this might be it. I'll check it next time this occurs.

Comment: @Depado Unfortunatly not.

Comment: @Depado I'm afraid I don't remember :/